# bind/named.conf configuration issue: append to primary zone

Tags: linux, dns, bind

I would like to do the following in bind (named.conf file), but I have not been able to figure it out.

kylevarga.com is hosted and uses name servers at hostgator.com:

```
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.kylevarga.com.     IN  NS
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.kylevarga.com.  3599    IN  CNAME   kylevarga.com.
kylevarga.com.      21599   IN  NS  ns906.hostgator.com.
kylevarga.com.      21599   IN  NS  ns905.hostgator.com.
```

What I would like to do is in my dns server, set up test.kylevarga.com that resolves to 127.0.0.1, but is not defined on ns906.hostgator.com. (I am running one on my network).

I've tried different combinations of forward only, forward first options and master or hint zone types.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am able to do this using
[dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) but not Bind. 

Anyone know of a solution?

**Dnsmasq will serve names from the /etc/hosts file (or an alternate). The names of local machines provided in this way become addressable without having to maintain /etc/hosts on each machine.**

Answer (score 0):

If you Point test.kylvarga.com to a specific computer in your local network you first need to create a forward lookup zone for kylvarga.com and then create the host test in that zone. The test host must Point to the ip address of the test host. If you Point test to 127.0.0.1 it will only Point to the correct host when you work on the bind server itself.
My suggestion is that you first create a couple of forward lookup zones like kylvarga.local and kylvarga.local and test name resolution from all your computers. Setting up Bind correctly takes some tíme.